# How can I run XBMC as another user?

Tags: multiple-monitors, permissions, sudo, xbmc

It's a little bit complicated as other "how can I run" questions, firstly, because I use this script to run on second screen (TV) full size:

```
   1 #! /bin/bash
   2 # Launch XBMC in windowed mode, then use wmctrl to remove the titlebar
   3
   4 # Select display 1
   5 # Separate X screennél 0.1 kell
   6 # twinviewnél meg egy monitor van, azaz 0.0
   7 DISPLAY=:0.0
   8
   9 # Start XBMC without blocking this script
  10 xbmc &
  11
  12 # Wait for the XBMC window to appear
  13 status=0
  14 while [ $status -eq 0 ]
  15 do
  16     sleep 1
  17  status=`wmctrl -x -l | grep "XBMC Media Center" | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'`
  18 done
  19
  20 # Force XBMC window to fullscreen
  21 #export SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_DISPLAY=1
  22 wmctrl -x -t 0 -r XBMC Media Center.XBMC Media Center -b toggle,fullscreen
```

and second, because XBMC want to connect to the other user's screen. I don't know anything about X sessions or how the screen permissions working. Is it possible at all ?

So how can I achieve that "kati" user could run this script as "walkman" user fully, but not anything else ?

Answer (score 1):

Add these lines at the top

```
if [[ ! $EUID == walkman_uid ]] ; then
    echo "this script must be run as walkman"
    exit 1
fi
```

If you do not know the uid of walkman, run

```
id walkman | awk '{print $1}'
```

As kati, run

```
sudo -u walkman /full/path/to/script
```

Personally I would put the script in `/usr/local/bin` and have it owned by root.

Comment: this doesnt work
it says:
`/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
No protocol specified
Error: unable to open display :1.0
No protocol specified
FEH.py: cannot connect to X server :1.0
No protocol specified
Cannot open display.`

Comment: So, it is running as "walkman" user but want to connect to "kati"-s screen to which walkman have no permission ?

Comment: It is a security feature. Take a look at xhost ;)

Comment: Now `06:16:37 T:140539983558528   ERROR: Unable to open audio mixer`

Comment: Maybe I should rather make an xbmc group whose files everybody can read, write in a shared folder...